# Looking for a proper name for this tensor.

Tags: tensors

Generally speaking, a scalar can be obtained from the self-contraction of a tensor, i.e.,

a=A:A

Does any one know what is a proper name for what the tensor A is to the scalar a?.

Best,
/UOMO.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Perhaps an example?

Comment: Sure, an example in 3D would be a first order tensor,
a=[A1 A2 A3]*[A1 A2 A3]'.
Or Generally in index notation for any dimension,
a=Aijklm...*Aijklm... .

Comment: It looks something like a scalar product, indeed, giving a well-defined linear map $V \otimes V \to k$ for a vector space $V$ over the field $k$ is the same as giving a scalar product.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, it is a contraction operation rather than a general tensor product. Anyway, what I would like to have is a name for what A is to a, being a=A:A. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the (square of the) [Hilbert-Schmidt Norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hilbert-SchmidtNorm.html).

Comment: Thank you Oscar. Indeed, it looks like a square root of such a norm. However, is it well-defined for tensors rather than for matrices as well?.

Comment: I don't think that people call that the Hilbert-Schmidt Norm (although they would understand what you were talking about). The contraction $A_{abc\dots d}A_{abc\dots d}$ itself is only well defined if you have a specified inner product on your vector space (otherwise you can't contract two "down" indices).